# Getting 401 / 406 error from node creation with authentication

Tags: 7, nodes, services, users

I am trying to create nodes with authentication with the services module enabled. So far I have done following things:

- Get services token from `http://localhost/drupal/services/session/token`.
- User authentication: I did trigger login web service and in return I got session name, id and complete user information. I called this web service by passing `X-CSRF-Token` which I got from previous web service. (http://localhost/drupal/myendpoint/user/login.json`)
- Node creation: I want to create article content type node. I am passing fields values in JSON and CSRF token and session information as following. (`http://localhost/drupal/myrest/node.create`)

  #### Body (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

  ```
  {
     "title":"Created through service",
     "type":"article",
     "body": {
        "value": "<p>test</p>\n",
        "format": "filtered_html"
     }
  }
  ```

  #### Headers

  - X-CSRF-Token: bla bla bla
  - `SESSion name: bla bla bla

The response I received from node create web service is the following:

> Status Code: 406
>      Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2015 23:43:31 GMT
>      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>      Server: Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12
>      X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.12
>      Content-Type: text/html
>      Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
>      Connection: Keep-Alive
>      Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
>      Content-Length: 0
>      Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT

Could you please let me know what I am doing incorrect while triggering node create web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging much I found solution by my self:

I will post step by step process to create a node with authentication.

---

```
Step 1: Get initial token.

    URL: `http://localhost/drupal/services/session/token`

    Method: GET
```

---

```
Step 2: Login

    URL: `http://localhost/drupal/myrest/user/login.json`

    Method: POST

    Content-Type: application/json

    Request payload - request parameter:

    X-CSRF-Token: <Token received from first web service response>
```

---

```
Step 3: Create node.

    URL: `http://localhost/drupal/myrest/node`

    Method: POST

    Content-Type: application/json

    Raw body:

    `{
          "title": "Sample post",
          "type": "article"
     }`

     Custom headers - request parameters:

     <session_name_value_received_from_previous_service_response>: <session_id_value_received_from_previous_service_response>

     Example: 

     SESS6a4470a2012aa23a7f83ea20ed1df766: KS43Muo_odeHA1KPI_kREWP6oK

     X-CSRF-Token: <token_value_received_from_previous_service_response>

     Example:

     X-CSRF-Token: JALApVoib7bGSFFh-59Saj9z5pT8q_5kP9BrHgGIO3E
```

---

And I am getting successful response:

`{"nid":"4","uri":"http://localhost/drupal/myrest/node/4"}`

Thanks all, please continue this thread if you face such issues. I will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the URL to `http://localhost/drupal/myrest/node`, the application type to  application/json, and the request method to POST; then, it should work.

Comment: Hi, thanks. If I do as per your instructions, it shows me 401 ["CSRF validation failed"] error.